# Mocking findViewById response with Robolectric and Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, robolectric

I have a custom ListView say `CustomListView`:

In a fragment there is:

```
<com.custom.CustomListView
    android:id="@+id/custom_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and in that fragment's source, I have

```
private CustomListView mCustomListView;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getActivity();

    mCustomListView = mContext.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview);
}
```

Then there is some method later:

```
public void doSomethingOnReceivingData(Data data) {
    mCustomListView.someCustomMethod(data);
}
```

I want to write test for `doSomethingOnReceivingData(Data)` method.

I can not figure out how to mock the listview so that I can continue with the test (ArgumentCaptors and stuff)?

Comment: Where from `mContext` coming?

Comment: @EugenMartynov mContext is `getActivity()`. I updated the question.

Comment: Added answer with information that you provided

Answer (score 1):

I would give to list field package local access and mock it in test directly. For our app it is already package accessible since we use **Butterknife**

Answer (score 1):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MainActivityFragmentTest {

    @Mock
    private CustomListView mCustomListView;

    @InjectMocks
    private MainActivityFragment fragment;

    @Test
    public void doSomethingOnReceivingData_callsCustomListView() {
        final String data = "data";

        fragment.doSomethingOnReceivingData(data);

        verify(mCustomListView).someCustomMethod(eq(data));
    }

}
```

Comment: `eq` matcher is not needed. I will explore `@InjectMocks` annotation. Thanks!